# cellForRowAt->Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In tableviewDelegate - cellforRowAt method..
I still try but it doesn't run.

I use custom tableview cell and show in tableview.

What is the reason for this error?

```
for i in 0..<4 {
    if modelInViewModel[indexPath.row].body_images[i] == nil {
        cell.uploadImageView![i].isHidden = true
    } else {
        let imageView = modelInViewModel[indexPath.row].body_images[i]
        cell.uploadImageView![i].image = UIImage(named: imageView!)             
    }
}
```

Comment: `cellforRowAr` is that a function you're defined? If not, what is the full name of the UITableDelegate function that is causing you a problem?

Comment: Oh, there seems to be a typo while posting a question
 ` override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell `

Comment: Your body_images could only contain less than 3 items?

Comment: Which line is giving you the error? You really should provide more information... is `uploadImageView` an **array** of image views in the cell class? Are there 4 of them? Does `body_images` have 4 elements?

Comment: error in second line and uploadImageView is [UIImageView]! @IBOutletCollection .... and body_images has 4 elements

Answer (score 1):

This answer will show you how to find what's causing your error - it'll be up to you to fix it.

---

First, you should (almost) never force-unwrap optionals with `!` -- that's just asking for crashes.

Also, you need to split up your lines of code to find the actual error. Replace your posted block of code with this:

```
    for i in 0..<4 {
        if i > modelInViewModel.count - 1 {
            fatalError("i = \(i) but modelInViewModel has only \(modelInViewModel.count) elements!")
        }
        let vm = modelInViewModel[indexPath.row]
        if i > vm.body_images.count - 1 {
            fatalError("i = \(i) but modelInViewModel[indexPath.row].body_images has only \(vm.body_images.count) elements!")
        }
        let imgViews = cell.uploadImageView!
        if i > imgViews.count - 1 {
            fatalError("i = \(i) but cell.uploadImageView has only \(imgViews.count) elements!")
        }

        // comment out your current code for now....
        //if modelInViewModel[indexPath.row].body_images[i] == nil {
        //  cell.uploadImageView![i].isHidden = true
        //} else {
        //  let imageView = modelInViewModel[indexPath.row].body_images[i]
        //  cell.uploadImageView![i].image = UIImage(named: imageView!)
        //}
    }
```

You should get a crash on (at least) one of those `fatalError` lines, and that will tell you where you're getting the `Index out of range` error.